How to make a keyboard shortcut for context menu item “Quick Actions -> Convert Image”?
In Finder app, I can control-click on an image, and in the resultant contextual menu, I can select “Quick Actions” and then “Convert Image”.
How can I create a keyboard shortcut to accomplish this, rather than having to mouse the trackpad around the popup menus?
I have already looked through System Settings, Keyboard, Keyboard Shortcuts, and all submenus there, to see if one already exists. And I have attempted to create an App Shortcut there for either All Applications or Finder.app, targeting “Quick Actions->Convert Image” and simply “Convert Image”.

A quick action should appear in Services in the Shortcuts panel. I can't test that to Sonoma, but it does in Mojave - https://i.sstatic.net/Ol9sbvR1.png

Your screenshot looks several OS versions out of date. I already mentioned I checked there, and it is not there.

Okay I managed to come up with a solution to your problem within the Shortcuts app. Here is a direct link to the shortcut.
Two things you might want to modify:

The resulting file type. Currently the shortcut converts the input file to JPEG, but you can modify it to whatever suits you.
In the info pane on the right you can modify the Keyboard Shortcut itself.



What is “the Shortcuts app”? What is that link? What is that screenshot? What am I supposed to do with this information?

You can read all about "the Shortcuts app" from the official: Intro to Shortcuts ( https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts-mac/intro-to-shortcuts-apdf22b0444c/mac )
